# How can i detection random points on (x,y) graphic and draw a pentagon

Tags: python, opencv

in Python im creating 10-20 random points on (x,y) graphic .

[My Output Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnhyP.jpg)

- But i'm trying to detect this all points and print coordinates and draw a pentagon on edge point.

[Trying To](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlEA5.jpg)

- In second picture , pentagon edges should take all points inside it. If anybody can help me or give me a advice or direct me to link i will be greatfull.
- Here's my codes ;

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

random.shuffle(x)
random.shuffle(y)
plt.scatter(x,y, color='k', s=100)
random.shuffle(x)
random.shuffle(y)

plt.scatter(x,y, color='k', s=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: do you mean polygon instead of pentagon? Try convex hull of all the points

Comment: @Micka thanks a lot , i saw at the moment . Btw how can i do this pentagon like a polygon inside the lines.