# Creating random points on (x,y) graphic in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, random

I need to  create  random points (Min 12- Max 18 points between) in (X,Y) graphic.

This points had to be between 0-9 x and y.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRt2j.jpg)

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,8,9]

y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,0,7,8,9]
print(x+y)

random.shuffle(x)

random.shuffle(y)

a=plt.scatter(x,y, color='k', s=100)

random.shuffle(x)

random.shuffle(y)

b=plt.scatter(x,y, color='k', s=100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Have you tried something already? How far did you get? What specifically did you get stuck on?

Comment: @PaulHankin thank you , i tried something and i'll edit post and add codes. But when i add to 0 value on point , label change like 0,2,4,6,8 but i need like 0,1,2,3,4 until 9

Comment: @PaulHankin honestly i'm trying to do this step by step:
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333166/how-can-i-detection-random-points-on-x-y-graphic-and-draw-a-pentagon  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint

amt = randint(12,19)

x = [randint(1,9) for _ in range(amt)]
y = [randint(1,9) for _ in range(amt)]

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: plt]

Comment: how can i get this all points coordinates like [x,y] in one list ?

Comment: `print(x)` `print(y)`

Comment: or, `for x,y in zip(x,y): print(x,y)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import random

coords = []
amount_of_coords = 12+random.randint(0, 7)
print(amount_of_coords)

for x in range(amount_of_coords):
    coords.append([random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10)])

print(coords)

for point in coords:
    plt.scatter(point[0],point[1], color='k', s=100)

plt.show()
```

output:

```
12
[[1, 1], [3, 7], [3, 1], [4, 0], [0, 7], [2, 1], [1, 0], [2, 8], [3, 4], [4, 6], [3, 7], [1, 4]]
```

[image]